# Spread values evenly between two times

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following code. I need to spread values out evenly between two times: now + 20 minutes to 15:30. The following code is a part of a loop that I did not include for the sake of brevity.

```
$numlines = count($data);

$calltime = date('U', strtotime('+20 minutes');

$to = date('U', strtotime('15:30'));
$from = $calltime;

$diffinsec = $to - $from;

$apptseparation = ceil($diffinsec / $numlines);

$calltime = date('H:i', strtotime('+' . $apptseparation . ' seconds', $calltime);
```

What I'm trying to do here is take the current time plus 20 minutes, convert it to a Unix epoch, and subtract it from 15:30 on the same day. The result should be the number of seconds between the two times.

I want to then divide the number of seconds by the total number of lines in my input file, giving me the total number of seconds between each value. Finally, I want to add this number to the existing $calltime variable so each iteration of the loop will add the new time.

What I have doesn't work, though. Date math always confuses me, and in PHP doubly so. If you need any more information, please let me know!

Comment: FYI: `date('U', strtotime(...))` === `strtotime(...)`. You don't need to convert a UNIX timestamp to a UNIX timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what are the result you get and the result you expect for?
This code seems to work if I well understood:

```
    $calltime = strtotime('+20 minutes');
    $from = $calltime;
    $to = strtotime('15:30');

    $diffinsec = $to - $from;
    if ( $diffinsec < 0 ) { // If it is 18:04 per example
        $diffinsec *= -1;
    }
    $apptseparation = ceil($diffinsec / $numlines);

    $calltime = date('H:i', strtotime('+'.$apptseparation.' seconds', $calltime));
```

Comment: Ahh, you know what? I bet it was the negative issue. I didn't even think to correct for that. Thanks!